# Xamarin forms, change absolutelayout with an animation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I implement a for example "Easing.Linear"-animation while the size of my label that is controlled with an AbsoluteLayout increases in size?

Right now If I do for example like this:

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (myLabel, new Rectangle (0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
```

The label indeed increases but It happens immediately. I would like to add an animation to it while it increases.

Any ideas how I can get this done?

UPDATE:
Made a bit of progress but the label now gets smaller and flies away topleft. No idea why it is happening because I am increasing the size with my new rectangle, not decreasing.

```
await myLabel.LayoutTo(new Rectangle (0.5, 0.4, 1.0, 0.6), 1000, Easing.Linear);
```

In my XAML I use this to my Label:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LayoutTo` method is pixel oriented, not proportional, so you need to give actual values instead of rates.

i.e: `await myLabel.LayoutTo(0.5*Width,0.4*Height,myLabel.Width,myLabel.Height);`

Comment: Is there anyway I can make an animation that is proportional oriented just the way that I work with the absolutelayout in my xaml? I cannot get it quite right when I work with pixels.

Comment: I have a huge problem controlling it with pixels, the size does not increase and the label just disappears if i raise the numbers